# Is there a way to initialize an object from a reference class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, delphi, reference

In Delphi, when i want to create an `object` from uncertain derived `class`, i was using `class of` statement;

```
TShape = class
public
  procedure Draw;
end;

TCircle = class(TShape)
public
  procedure Draw;
end;

TShapeClassRef = class of TShape;
```

and i was creating object as;

```
var
  ref:TShapeClassRef;
  drawing:TShape;
begin
  ref:=TCircle;
  drawing:=ref.Create;
  drawing.draw; //this is a circle object, and it draws circle
end;
```

I couldn't find anything like that in c#.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Activator.CreateInstance(yourTypeGoesHere)`?

Comment: C# does not have metaclasses. So no direct analog. Yes you can use reflection but I really don't like that. I personally think the best way is as I wrote in an answer at the linked dupe: *And yet another option is to replace your dictionary of classes with a dictionary of delegates that return a new instance of your object. With lambda syntax that option yields very clean code.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Type` like this:

```
public class TShape { }
```

And:

```
Type t = typeof(TShape);
```

To initialize an object through `t` variable, use `Activator.CreateInstance(t)`:

```
Shape shp = (Shape)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Comment: that's just the half of my question, how should i initialize an object through "t" variable

Type t = typeof(TCircle);
Shape shp = new t();

?

Comment: Like this: Shape shp = (Shape)Activator.CreateInstance(t); see my Updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much, you've been realy helpfull :)

Comment: How to pass parameters to the constructor?